# Convert a date into 'YYYYMMDDHH24miSS' format

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert dates having this format '2012/11/24 13:32' into this format 'YYYYMMDDHH24miSS'.

I've tried using to_char and to_timestamp functions, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a char to date and than a date to char conversion?

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date('2012/11/24 13:32','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi'),'YYYYMMDDHH24miSS') res from dual;

RES
--------------
20121124133200
```

Regards